# Javascript object property: string or int?

Tags: javascript, json, types, javascript-objects, typeof

Let's say I have the following object:

```js
var obj {
    name: "Jack", 
    id: 4, 
    year: "2004"
}
```

I want to iterate through the properties and print out the property type:

```js
for (var i in obj) {
    console.log(i + ' (' + (typeof i) + ') ' + obj[i];
}
```

The problem is that every type shows as a `string`:

> name: (string) Jack
>
> id: (string) 4
>
> year: (string) 2004

How can I get output the types of `"Jack"` and `"2004"` as `string` and `4` as `integer`/`numeric` or something?

Comment: What's the real code ? Where does i come from ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret What do you mean where's the real code? It's all there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are outputting the type of your key, not the value. It should be:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    console.log(prop + ' (' + (typeof obj[prop]) + ') ' + obj[prop])
}                                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

That would output:

```
name (string) Jack
id (number) 4
year (string) 2004
```